# Como consultar un API con id en Alamofire?

Tags: api, swift, alamofire

Estoy tratando de consultar un API

pero la url sería algo así:

```
xxxxxx/ApiRest/api/Usuario/{id}?passwd={passwd}
```

Desde Alamofire pero no veo la manera correcta.

Logré hacerlo funcionar pero no sé si es correcto:

```
let encondeURL = apiLogin
let encondeURLUser = encondeURL + txtUser.txt!
let parameters = ["passwd": txtPasswd.text]
```

El problema es que paso los valores directos.

Comment: Si funciona entonces cuál es la pregunta y cuál es el error que tiene el código? Cómo tienes la llamada con Alamofire? `GET` o `POST`?

Answer (score 0):

lo que creo que deseas hacer es que el usuario escriba su contraseña y con ello consultar el API.

Lo que yo haría sería obtener la contraseña del usuario a partir de un UITextField, a partir de ese texto llamar una función con una entrada tipo String; en esta función añadir a tu url base la contraseña y hacer el request con Alamofire.

Ejemplo:

```
let urlBase = "xxxxxx/ApiRest/api/Usuario/{id}?"

if let contraseña = textField.text {

    let urlEntero = "\(urlBase)passwd=\(contraseña)"

    fetchRequest(urlString: urlEntero)

}


func fetchRequest(urlString: String) {

    Alamofire.request(urlString).responseJSON .....
```